# WebLogic Console - No application files exist when redeploying application

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic11g

When stopping/starting a deployment via the WebLogic Admin console, sometimes we get the following error:

```
Unable to access application source information in '/opt/product/oracle/local/managedservers/mydomain/servers/serverA/stage/apputil/apputil.war' 
for application 'apputil’. 
The specific error is: [Deployer:149158] No application files 
exist at '/opt/product/oracle/local/managedservers/mydomain/servers/serverA/stage/apputil/apputil.war'
```

Yet, if I stop and start the managed server, the deployment appears to come back.

My question is, **WHY do these war files disappear from the managed server seemingly randomly, while the server is running?**  This typically happens after we haven't touched a deployment for some time (6 months).  Other war files for other deployments are there. It does not affect the running of the app, until we try to stop/start it.

This is what the filesystem looks like before and after.

```
[oracle@serverA stage]$ pwd;ls -alstr
/opt/product/oracle/local/managedservers/mydomain/servers/serverA/stage
total 20
4 drwxr-x--- 8 oracle dba 4096 Mar 19  2014 ..
4 drwxr----- 3 oracle dba 4096 Mar 19  2014 app-crypto-util
4 drwxr----- 2 oracle dba 4096 Mar 19  2014 appadmin
4 drwxr----- 2 oracle dba 4096 Mar 19  2014 appsm
4 drwxr----- 5 oracle dba 4096 May  1 15:29 .

[oracle@serverA stage]$ ls
appadmin  app-crypto-util  appsm
```

Restart managed server here...

```
[oracle@serverA stage]$ ls
appdmin  app-crypto-util  appsm  apputil

[oracle@serverA stage]$ ls -alstr
total 24
4 drwxr-x--- 8 oracle dba 4096 Mar 19  2014 ..
4 drwxr----- 3 oracle dba 4096 Mar 19  2014 app-crypto-util
4 drwxr----- 2 oracle dba 4096 Mar 19  2014 appadmin
4 drwxr----- 2 oracle dba 4096 Mar 19  2014 appsm
4 drwxr----- 2 oracle dba 4096 Jun 25 14:35 apputil
4 drwxr----- 6 oracle dba 4096 Jun 25 14:35 .

[oracle@serverA stage]$ ls -alstr apputil/apputil.war 
28660 -rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 29347298 Jun 25 14:35 apputil/apputil.war
```

Answer (score 11):

This may happen when AdminServer & Managed Server are in different machines, or the war is being sent from a different machine to AS.

use arguments: `-remote -upload`

i.e.:

```
java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://200.10.10.125:7001 -verbose -username weblogic -password welcome1 -deploy -targets WLCluster -name sample -remote -source sample.war -upload
```

Comment: I had -remote.  Deploy was successful after adding -upload.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Referring to the stage directory modification date, it appears this dir is created/edited when an event occur, maybe by a script, and if it is the case, the problem should come from that script when copying apps wars.

So in my POV when stopping a deployment, maybe weblogic stop the apputil managed server, wich delete the war from th stage dir, and when starting a deployment after stopping it, it does not start the specified managed server before, and try to redeploy all apps wich cause the exception.

Comment: It probably got created when the managed server was restarted.

Comment: Correct, I know it got created and redeployed after the restart. But I want to know what deleted it (even though it's been running for months).  This happens on several of our domains that have infrequent deployments/restarts.